# Can I change Spring Batch configuration to run statically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

[Spring Batch] When @Scheduled annotation is used, it is executed dynamically. Can I change it to run statically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you mention @Scheduled, I imagine your batch is executed from a web application. If you want to run it out of the box, you can :

- use Spring boot to start your batch by launching a spring boot application : I advise you to follow this tuto and replace the example batch by your own : https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/
- start your batch manually from a classic java application which create a spring context at start (so spring boot does the job really better)
- start your batch as a unit test (for integration purpose) : you can folow this tuto (which also use spring boot) :https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-testing-job

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

I think I misunderstood your question.
If you want to run from static method there is one way to do this. You can make StaticJobInitializer component like this

```
@Component
public class StaticJobInitializer {

    private JobRegistry jobRegistry;
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    public StaticJobInitializer(JobRegistry jobRegistry, JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        this.jobRegistry = jobRegistry;
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        StaticJobRun.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        StaticJobRun.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
    }
}
```

```
public final class StaticJobRun {
    private static JobRegistry jobRegistry;
    private static JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    public static JobRegistry getJobRegistry() {
        return jobRegistry;
    }

    public static JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    public static void setJobLauncher(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        StaticJobRun.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    }

    public static void setJobRegistry(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
        StaticJobRun.jobRegistry = jobRegistry;
    }
}
```

and than your start job static method should be like this:

```
public static void startJob(){
    Job job = StaticJobRun.getJobRegistry().getJob("job_name");
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .toJobParameters();
            StaticJobRun.getJobLauncher().run(job, new JobParameters());
}
```